# How can I make a CSS Hover not work if a button is disabled?

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
html.darkBlue .btn1 button:hover:not(.nohover) {
  background: #0007d5;
  border: 1px solid #0007d5;
  color: white;
}
```

I am rather confused about disabled. How can I make it so that this CSS does not work if the button is disabled?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE < 9 you could use the [`:enabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#UIstates) pseudo class.

```
html.darkBlue .btn1 button:hover:enabled {
    background: #0007d5;
    border: 1px solid #0007d5;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: For folks concerned with IE < 9 support, :disabled has the same browser compatibility than :enabled.

Comment: For folks concerned with IE < 9 support, :disabled has the same browser compatibility than :enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try with (demo http://jsfiddle.net/JDNLk/)

HTML

```
<button class="btn1" disabled="disabled">disabled</button>
<button class="btn1">enabled</button>
```

CSS

```
html.darkBlue .btn1 button:hover:not([enabled="enabled"]) {
  background: #0007d5;
  border: 1px solid #0007d5;
  color: white;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [negation pseudo class selector (CSS 3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation). I am not sure if there is also a solution using [attribute selectors (CSS 2.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

Given this html

```
  <div class="darkBlue">
    <h2>disable hover for disabled buttons</h2>
    <div class="btn2">
      <button>hover enabled</button>    <br/>     
      <button disabled="disabled">hover disabled</button>         
    </div>  
  </div>
```

and this css

```
.darkBlue .btn2 button:hover:not([disabled="disabled"]) {
  background: #0007d5;
  border: 1px solid #0007d5;
  color: white;   
}
```

you can achive that every button inside the matiching selector has no hover-style applied.
See [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BbCfp).

At [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) you can find tables that compare which browser supports which selector

- browser support for  [css2 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)
- browser support for  [css3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

#### Update using a hack to be able to use css2 selectors

This is a hack and is yet not exactly the same but in case you are restricted to css 2.1 this may be a starting point. If you define a seperate style-rule for disabled buttons and use the color that you picked for disabled buttons you can fake a disabled hover-style:

```
.btn3 button[disabled="disabled"]:hover
{
  background-color: rgb(212, 208, 200);
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after adding the ":enabled" selector as following :

```
element-class:hover:enabled {
  properties...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS :Not attribute selector to only target elements that don't have the disabled attribute.

```
html.darkBlue .btn1 button:not([disabled]):hover
```

That way your hover style will only be applied to buttons that are not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn:disabled:hover{color:default-color;background:default prop}
```

.   or .btn:disabled{pointer-events:none}